# Subsetting on a condition for two rows at the same time

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data.table (pooled cross section) as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"ID country year Event
1   NLD   1998  0
2   NLD   1998  0
3   NLD   1998  0
4   NLD   2002  0
5   NLD   2002  0
6   NLD   2006  1
7   NLD   2006  1
8   NLD   2006  1
9   GBR   2002  0
10  GBR   2002  0
11  GBR   2002  0
12  GBR   2006  1
13  GBR   2006  1
14  GRC   2001  0
15  GRC   2007  0
16  USA   2001  1   
17  USA   2001  1   
18  USA   2007  0",
header = TRUE)
```

I want to create a subset with the following condition;

If the `Event` is `1` for a combination of `country` and `year`, and
the `Event` is `0` for the previous `year` of that `country, take both rows.

I tried to do the following:

```
DT <- DT[Event==1 & shift(Event==0), ,by=c("country ","year")]
DT <- DT[Event==1 & shift(Event)==0,, by=c("country ","year")]
```

But that is not allowed.

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(DT, Event== 1 & shift(Event) ==  :
  Ignoring by= because j= is not supplied
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Desired output:

```
DT <- fread(
"ID country year Event
4   NLD   2002  0
5   NLD   2002  0
6   NLD   2006  1
7   NLD   2006  1
8   NLD   2006  1
9   GBR   2002  0
10  GBR   2002  0
11  GBR   2002  0
12  GBR   2006  1
13  GBR   2006  1",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: `DT[, .SD[Event==1 & shift(Event)==0], by = c("country","year")]`?

Comment: Hey Jaap, thank you for your comment. If I apply your suggestion I get: `Empty data.table (0 rows and 4 cols): country,year,ID,Event`, both on the example and my actual data.

Comment: I get that also; see for a possible solution my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
DT[DT[DT[, .I[Event == 1 & shift(Event, fill = 1) == 0] + (-1:0)
         , by = .(country)]$V1
      , .(country, year)]
   , on = .(country, year)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     ID country year Event
>  1:  4     NLD 2002     0
>  2:  5     NLD 2002     0
>  3:  6     NLD 2006     1
>  4:  7     NLD 2006     1
>  5:  8     NLD 2006     1
>  6:  9     GBR 2002     0
>  7: 10     GBR 2002     0
>  8: 11     GBR 2002     0
>  9: 12     GBR 2006     1
> 10: 13     GBR 2006     1
> ```

---

Explanation:

- With `DT[, .I[Event == 1 & shift(Event, fill = 1) == 0] + (-1:0), by = .(country)]` we look up the rows that meet the condition. This results in the following table with rownumbers by country that meet the condition:

  ```
     country V1
  1:     NLD  5
  2:     NLD  6
  3:     GBR 11
  4:     GBR 12
  ```
- Next, with `$V1` the rownumbers are extracted and used to subset `DT` with only the columns `country` and `year` in:

  ```
  DT[DT[, .I[Event == 1 & shift(Event, fill = 1) == 0] + (-1:0)
        , by = .(country)]$V1
     , .(country, year)]
  ```

  which results in:

  ```
     country year
  1:     NLD 2002
  2:     NLD 2006
  3:     GBR 2002
  4:     GBR 2006
  ```
- Finally, this is joined with the original `DT` on the `country` and `year` columns with `on = .(country, year)` to only keep the countries for which the condition applies.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked like a charm. I would really be interested in the explanation of this code if you would have the time some time. But in any case thank you for solving a big issue I was having!

Comment: @Tom I've added an explanation